# Conditional Parameter inside dictionary Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

From my dataframe here:

```
    OrigC  OrigZ  OrigN Weigh  DestC   DestZ    DestN    Mvt
0      PL     97    TP    59     DE      63       SN     DD
1      TR     23    GH    66     SN      65       US     DP
```

I want to pass conditional parameter in my dictionary based on the value of a column from my dataframe.

My code looks like this without the condition :

```
dic = {}
dic['section'] = []
for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    
    in_dict = {
        'location': {
            'zip_code': {
                'OrigC': row['OrigC'],
                'OrigZ': row['OrigZ'],
                },
            'location': {'id': 1}, 
            'OrigN': 'TP',  
        },
        'CarriageParameter': {
            'road': {
                'truckLoad': 'Auto'}
            },
        'load': {
            'Weigh': str(row['Weigh']),
        } 
        }
    
    
    dic['section'].append(in_dict)
```

I want to pass a condition inside my dictionary like this somehow wont work:

```
dic = {}
dic['section'] = []
for ix, row in df.iterrows():

    in_dict = {
        'location': {
            if row['Mvt'] = 'DP':
                return 'zip_code': {
                'OrigC': row['OrigC'],
                'OrigZ': row['OrigZ'],
                }
            elif row['Mvt'] = 'DD':
                return 'iata_code': {
                'OrigC': row['OrigN'],
                }
            'location': {'id':1}, 
            'OrigN': 'TP',  
        },
        'CarriageParameter': {
            'road': {
                'truckLoad': 'Auto'}
            },
        'load': {
            'Weigh': str(row['Weigh']),
        } 
        }


dic['section'].append(in_dict)
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at inline if-statements for python if you want too keep all the conditioning inside the dictionary

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Have the common key value pairs in the `in_dict` dictionary setup initially, and later update the dictionary according to the condition.

```py
dic = {}
dic['section'] = []
for ix, row in df.iterrows():

    in_dict = {
        'location': {
        'CarriageParameter': {
            'road': {
                'truckLoad': 'Auto'
            }
        },
        'load': {
            'Weigh': str(row['Weigh']),
        } 
    }

    if row['Mvt'] == 'DP':
        in_dict['location']['zip_code'] = {
            'OrigC': row['OrigC'],
            'OrigZ': row['OrigZ'],
        }
    elif row['Mvt'] == 'DD':
        in_dict['location']['iata_code'] = {
            'OrigC': row['OrigN']
        }
    in_dict['location']['location'] = {'id':1}
    in_dict['location']['OrigN'] = 'TP'

dic['section'].append(in_dict)
```